# Visual-Studio tutorial on how to make all code in one directory and all sln and proj stuff in another?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, project-management, projects-and-solutions

So what I want is to develop a project easily portable / compilable across diffident platforms. I use only crossplatform libs. But My First priority currently is windows os so I am using Visual Studio for main development. Structure I  Want to achieve looks like:

```
  !MainFolderForSolution
    !SolutionBuildDebugFolder
    - solution.sln
    - project1.vcproj
    - libUsedInproject1.vcproj
    !FolderForProject1
      - main.cpp
    !LibUsedInproject1
      - lib.cpp
      - lib.h
```

my point is that top level with projects and sln can be some make file or qt proj etc.

What I really need as a beginner is not only where to look but alsow how to do it... step by step.

So how to do such thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider using [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/project/about.html).

It supports out of place builds (which supports a directory structure similar to yours), but also would assist in automatically generating and maintaining your other build settings, such as Qt or makefile based builds for cross platform development.

Comment: Hm... hm... Can it be integrated into VS? (I do not want to loose VS text editor - I have visual assist x so I can say I am super happy to develop in VS... exept project files structuring part)

Comment: @Kabumbus: Yes.  You build the cmake file, and when you run it, it generates a Visual Studio solution.  You still work in VS 100% of the time.  The only difference is, when you adda  file, you add it in the cmake project, and re-run cmake, and it changes/regenerates your Visual Studio solution and project files...

Comment: But - the nice thing is that you can automatically generate other types of projects from the same project for cross platform development, such as XCode projects on mac, etc.

Comment: Grate - I installed CMake... I opened its gui. I tried some... but for me - C beginner it is not clear... at all how to create desired project structure. So could you please give a tutorial on that?

Comment: official != a tutorial for nube=(

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, right-click on your project, go to -> Properties | Configuration Properties | General. There you can set the Output Directory and the Intermediate Directory.

Comment: and how to move .vcproj projects from folders with project files?

Comment: @Kabumbus: all project paths are relative to the directory containing the .vcproj file for the project. So either use an absolute path or do someting like ..\FolderForProject1\

Comment: @Kabumbus, I don't understand the question. Where do you need them setup?

Answer (score 1):

When adding files to a project in Visual Studio, you are asked where to put them at the bottom.
`Name: [<Enter_Name>....]`
`Location: [D:\Path\ProjectName\...] [Browse...]`
Just hit browse and browse to the location where you want to store your files.
Hope this helps, if not, comment and maybe phrase the question a bit better. :)